# Storing every number that bigger than 600 to store another vector but is not printing numbers

Tags: r, vector

I tried if vec2 > 600 save it to va

```
 set.seed(75)
 Vec2 <- sample(0:999, size = 100)

 print(Vec2)
 va <- (Vec2 > 600)
 print(va)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
set.seed(75)
Vec2 <- sample(0:999, size = 100)

print(Vec2)
#>   [1] 703 167 792 788 872 758 202 925 472 463 823 596 928 274 290 190 599 943
#>  [19] 321  95 745 587 971 635 432 300 818 415 878 914 139 926 806 677  49 832
#>  [37] 610 531 175 678 501 462 148 645 958 213 731 367 912 523 324  80 133 473
#>  [55] 235 976 595 239   1 785 591 533 908 750 455 946 435 384 223 510  97 853
#>  [73]  24 742 757 713 685 149 699 690 334 841 104 604 549 436 271 141 695 934
#>  [91] 129 932 561 439 296 897 174 727 445 396

va <- Vec2[(Vec2 > 600)]
print(va)
#>  [1] 703 792 788 872 758 925 823 928 943 745 971 635 818 878 914 926 806 677 832
#> [20] 610 678 645 958 731 912 976 785 908 750 946 853 742 757 713 685 699 690 841
#> [39] 604 695 934 932 897 727
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>